# Calculating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}x \, dx\;$ using $\frac{(e^z - 1)}{z}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

In on of my books there is an exercise to calculate  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\sin(x)}x \, dx$.

There is a hint given that one should consider the entire function $\dfrac{(e^z - 1)}{z}$. But I really have no idea how to interpret 
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\sin(x)} x\, dx$ as an complex integral 
involving this function.

I would appreciate some hints.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt This is not exactly a duplicate of that particular question. The approach the OP is asking about is not discussed there.

Comment: @RandomVariable That is true, though the OP might be open to any approach to this problem, following the hint in the book is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** for real $x$,
 $$ \operatorname{Im}\left( \frac{e^{ix}-1}{x} \right) = \frac{\sin{x}}{x}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly more direct way of looking at it would be to notice the real part of $\frac{e^z - 1}{z}$ (for $z$ on the imaginary axis) is $\frac{\sin t}{t}$, and the imaginary part is also an odd function.